UnsatisfiedDependencyException related to the mongoTemplate bean Spring boot
i'm facing this error : Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongoTemplate' while setting bean property 'mongoOperations' with my spring boot app not knowing the reason or what to do , i'm using both mySql and mongoDb in one app which i already did before and its working the same way in an other app with no problem , i don't know exactly what to do with it or why this error is showing ,generally this is my code :
app props :
spring.application.name=Inventory
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/inventory
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://localhost:27017/
spring.data.mongodb.database=mongoInventory
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
logging.level.org.springframework.data.mongodb=DEBUG
logging.level.org.springframework=DEBUG
server.error.include-exception=true
server.error.include-stacktrace=always
spring.main.allow-circular-references=true
logging.level.org.hibernate=TRACE

Gradle Build :
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.2.5'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.4'
}

group = 'com.InventoryCHU'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

java {
    sourceCompatibility = '21'
}

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-api:0.11.5'
    implementation 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-impl:0.11.5'
    implementation 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-jackson:0.11.5'
    implementation group: 'org.python', name: 'jython-slim', version: '2.7.3'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    implementation 'com.h2database:h2'
    implementation 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:0.9.1' // JWT library
    runtimeOnly 'com.mysql:mysql-connector-j'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'


}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

all my reps are like that :
package com.InventoryCHU.Inventory.Repository;

import com.InventoryCHU.Inventory.Models.BreakDown;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;

import java.util.Optional;

public interface BreakDownRepository extends MongoRepository<BreakDown , String> {
    Optional<BreakDown> findBreakDownByItemId(String item);
}

Service :
package com.InventoryCHU.Inventory.Services;

import com.InventoryCHU.Inventory.Models.BreakDown;
import com.InventoryCHU.Inventory.Repository.BreakDownRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@Service
public class BreakDownService {
    @Autowired
    BreakDownRepository breakDownRepository;

    public List<BreakDown> getAllBreakDowns(){
        return breakDownRepository.findAll();
    }

    public Optional<BreakDown> getBreakDownById(String Id){
        return breakDownRepository.findById(Id);
    }

    public BreakDown createBreakDown(BreakDown breakDown){
        return breakDownRepository.save(breakDown);
    }

    public void deleteBreakDown(String Id){
        breakDownRepository.deleteById(Id);
    }

    public Optional<BreakDown> findBreakDownByItemId(String productId){ return breakDownRepository.findBreakDownByItemId(productId); }

}


controller :
package com.InventoryCHU.Inventory.Controllers;

import com.InventoryCHU.Inventory.Models.BreakDown;
import com.InventoryCHU.Inventory.Services.BreakDownService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/breakdown")
public class BreakDownController {
    @Autowired
    BreakDownService breakDownService;

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<List<BreakDown>> getAllBreakDowns() {
        List<BreakDown> breakDowns = breakDownService.getAllBreakDowns();
        return ResponseEntity.ok(breakDowns);
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<BreakDown> getBreakDownById(@PathVariable String id) {
        Optional<BreakDown> breakDown = breakDownService.getBreakDownById(id);
        return breakDown.map(ResponseEntity::ok)
                .orElse(ResponseEntity.notFound().build());
    }

    @GetMapping("/product-{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<BreakDown> getBreakDownByUserId(@PathVariable("id") String productId){
        Optional<BreakDown> breakDown = breakDownService.findBreakDownByItemId(productId);
        return breakDown.map(ResponseEntity::ok)
                .orElse(ResponseEntity.notFound().build());
    }

    @PostMapping(consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<BreakDown> createBreakDown(@RequestBody BreakDown breakDown) {
        BreakDown createdBreakDown = breakDownService.createBreakDown(breakDown);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(createdBreakDown);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/delete/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> deleteBreakDown(@PathVariable String id) {
        breakDownService.deleteBreakDown(id);
        return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
    }

}

for the error showing its too long so i think its better to only show this :
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'breakDownController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'breakDownService': Error creating bean with name 'breakDownService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'breakDownRepository': Error creating bean with name 'breakDownRepository' defined in com.InventoryCHU.Inventory.Repository.BreakDownRepository defined in @EnableMongoRepositories declared on MongoRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableMongoRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongoTemplate' while setting bean property 'mongoOperations'
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'breakDownService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'breakDownRepository': Error creating bean with name 'breakDownRepository' defined in com.InventoryCHU.Inventory.Repository.BreakDownRepository defined in @EnableMongoRepositories declared on MongoRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableMongoRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongoTemplate' while setting bean property 'mongoOperations'
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'breakDownRepository' defined in com.InventoryCHU.Inventory.Repository.BreakDownRepository defined in @EnableMongoRepositories declared on MongoRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableMongoRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongoTemplate' while setting bean property 'mongoOperations'
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDatabaseFactoryDependentConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'mongoTemplate' parameter 1: Error creating bean with name 'mappingMongoConverter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDatabaseFactoryDependentConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'mappingMongoConverter' parameter 1: Error creating bean with name 'mongoMappingContext' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDataConfiguration.class]: Unable to make field private java.util.Date java.security.Timestamp.timestamp accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.security" to unnamed module @3c9754d8
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mappingMongoConverter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDatabaseFactoryDependentConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'mappingMongoConverter' parameter 1: Error creating bean with name 'mongoMappingContext' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDataConfiguration.class]: Unable to make field private java.util.Date java.security.Timestamp.timestamp accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.security" to unnamed module @3c9754d8
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoMappingContext' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDataConfiguration.class]: Unable to make field private java.util.Date java.security.Timestamp.timestamp accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.security" to unnamed module @3c9754d8
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private java.util.Date java.security.Timestamp.timestamp accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.security" to unnamed module @3c9754d8``

i don't know exactly what to try , i looked on google but i didn't find anything about it , i also tried gpt all it said is incompatible version between java and mongodb and UnsatisfiedDependencyException related to the mongoTemplate bean without giving any working solution , if any idea for the solution i will be glad for it

Use latest JDK (22) and latest MongoDB, dependencies (latest technology/dependencies stack). Then share to me the result. If you have github repo, share it.

Have you read the error? Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private java.util.Date java.security.Timestamp.timestamp accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.security" to unnamed module @3c9754d8 Looks pretty clear. You are using types (old java.util and java.security in your types which you shouldn't be using in the first place. Use the newer java.time ones.

Provide the code for the BreakDown class

after testing for one day the whole error was related to using timeStamp type instead of LocalDateTime , in case you passed by this error and you know a way how to manage displaying errors in a more detailed way in spring boot other than :
server.error.include-exception=true
server.error.include-stacktrace=always

please mention it on a comment.
